# Why does ... == True return False in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, truthiness

I am learning python, but I'm a bit confused by the following result.

```
In [41]: 1 == True
Out[41]: True

In [42]: if(1):
    ...:     print('111')
    ...:     
111

In [43]: ... == True
Out[43]: False <===== why this is False while '1 == True' is True in previous sample

In [44]: if (...): <==== here ... just behaves like True
    ...:     print('...')
    ...:     
...
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), `...` has a truth value of True.

But I still feel the above code a bit inconsistent.

...And something more interesting:

```
In [48]: 2==True
Out[48]: False <===== why 1==True returns True while 2==True returns False?

In [49]: if(2):
    ...:     print('222')
    ...:     
222
```

Comment: `bool(...) == True` --> `True`

Comment: FWIW, `bool(...)` returns `True`

Comment: @ReutSharabani Thanks but that still can't resolve my unrest about my experiment result.

Comment: "Has a truth value of true" doesn't mean "== True".

Comment: You are confusing *evaluating to `True`* with *being equal to `True`*. Python booleans are `ints`, `1 == True` and `0 == False`, but any(?) non-empty non-zero object evaluates to `True`, as you can see with `bool()`

Comment: `1 == True` is because `bool` inherits from `int`. Whether this is a good idea or not (cf Ruby) it's unlikely to change in Python. For this reason you should get into the habit of using `x is True`, `x is False`, or `x is None` for those situations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're mixing two concepts: equality testing and truth-value testing. They are not the same in Python.

I think what triggered the question is that Python **does** an implicit casting when you do `if something` (it casts the something to `bool`) but it **does not** do implicit casting when you do `something1 == something2`.

Pythons data model actually explains how these operations are done:

#### [Truth-value testing](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

- It starts by checking if the object implements the `__bool__` method and if it does it uses the returned boolean.
- If it doesn't define a `__bool__` method it looks at the `__len__` method. If it's implemented it will use the result of `len(obj) != 0`.
- If it doesn't have either the object is considered `True`.

For integers the [`__bool__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/longobject.c#L4279-L4283) returns `True` except when the integer value is `0` (then it's `False`).

The Ellipsis object ([`...` is the Ellipsis object](https://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#Ellipsis)) on the other hand [doesn't implement `__bool__` or `__len__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/sliceobject.c#L58-L59) so it's always `True`.

#### [Equality testing](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Equality testing relies on the `__eq__` method of **both** arguments. It's more a chain of operations:

- It checks if the first operand implements `__eq__` when the second operand is passed as argument.
- If it doesn't then it checks if the second operand implements `__eq__` when the first operand is passed as argument.
- If it doesn't then Python checks for object identity (if they are the same object - similar to pointer comparisons in C-like languages)

The order of these operations may vary.<sup>1</sup>

For built-in Python types these operations are explicitly implemented. For example [`int`egers implement `__eq__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/longobject.c#L2914-L2950) but the [`CHECK_BINOP`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/longobject.c#L1413-L1417) makes sure that it returns `NotImplemented` if the other one isn't an `int`eger.

The `Ellipsis` object [doesn't implement `__eq__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/sliceobject.c#L71) at all.

So when you compare integers and Ellipsis Python will always fallback to object identity and so it will always return `False`.

On the other hand `bool`eans are a subclass of `int`egers so they actually compare with `int` (they are another `int` after all). The booleans are implemented as `1` (`True`) and `0` (`False`). So they compare equal:

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 0 == False
True

>>> 1 == False
False
>>> 0 == True
False
```

---

Even though the source code is probably hard to understand I hope I explained the concepts well enough (the source code is for the CPython implementation, the implementation in other Python implementations like PyPy, IronPython may differ!). The important take-away message should be that Python doesn't do implicit conversions in equality checks and equality testing is not related to truth value testing at all. The built-in types are implemented that they almost always give senseable results:

- all number-types implement equality in some way (floats compare to integers, complex compare to integers and floats)
- and everything not-zero and not-empty is `truthy`.

However if you create your own classes you can override equality and truth value testing as you like (and then you can spread a lot of confusion)!

---

<sup>1</sup> In some cases the order is changed:

1. If the second operand is a subclass of the first operand the first two steps are reversed.
2. For some **implicit equality checks** the object identity is checked before any `__eq__` methods are called. For example when checking if some item is in a list, i.e. `1 in [1,2,3]`.

Comment: @Claudio Well, that's kind of the point I was trying to make: The casting isn't implicit it has to be implemented **explicitly** in either operands `__eq__` method. And the built-in types don't do explicit casting, they hard-code the comparison between different types (or return `False` if incomparable). You might want to take a look at how complicated that get's for [`float == int`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/floatobject.c#L328-L528).

Answer (score 6):

Any object can be tested for ["truthiness"](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **bool**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False. [1]
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations or and and always return one of their operands.)

So it's not hard to see that `if ...` will enter the branch. The `Ellipsis` object is considered `true`. However that doesn't mean it has to be equal to `True`. Just the `bool(...) == True`!

The `if` will implicitly call `bool` on the condition, so:

```
if ...:
    # something
```

will be evaluated as if you had written:

```
if bool(...):
    # something
```

and:

```
>>> bool(...)
True
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(2)
True
```

However there's one catch here. `True` is equal to `1` and `False` equal to `0`, but that's just because `bool` subclasses `int`eger in python.

Comment: Clearest answer, I upvoted. Interesting that although `if ...:` always gives the same output as `if bool(...):`, the CPython implementation seems different, at least from a quick comparison with `dis.dis()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands It's not identical because `if ...` will check the truth-value of `...` (which is True) in the other case it will first convert `...` to a boolean object (`True`) and then check the truth value of `True` (which is also `True`). But the result will be the same.

Comment: How does it "check the truth-value" though? That doesn't involve some kind of boolean conversion but instead some kind of look-up?

Comment: @Chris_Rands It either uses [`PyObject_IsTrue`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_IsTrue) or [`PyObject_Not`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Not). These will call the `__bool__` (and `__len__`) method or the C equivalents. `bool()` also uses the same special methods _but_ besides checking for the truth value it will explicitly return a boolean object. So when you have `if bool(...)` you actually call `(...).__bool__().__bool__()` and with `if ...` you call `(...).__bool__()`. That's not 100% correct because we're dealing with C functions and types.

Answer (score 1):

In python most (all?) objects have a `bool` value. The meaning behind "has a truth value of True" means that `bool(obj)` evaluates to True.

On the other hand, `True` is treated as `1` in many cases (and `False` as `0`) which you can see when you do stuff like:

```
sum([True, True, False])
# (1 + 1 + 0) -> 2
```

That is why you get `1 == True` --> `True`

There is a more explicit [explanation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values) in the documentation:

> Boolean values are the two constant objects False and True. They are used to represent truth values (although other values can also be considered false or true). **In numeric contexts (for example when used as the argument to an arithmetic operator), they behave like the integers 0 and 1, respectively**

From the [type-hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) itself in the docs:

> These represent the truth values False and True. The two objects representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects. The Boolean type is a subtype of the integer type, and **Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts**, the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's `1 == True` here is that's weird, not that `... != True`.

`1` equals with `True` because in Python booleans are subclass of integers (because of [PEP-285](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/)). See yourself:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

Comment: Just a minor point: `hash`es don't matter when testing for equality (except in `dict` and `set`).

Comment: Ah, right. I thought still matters a little because of CPython treats `small_ints` (-5...+257) specially, always allocating the same instance, but it seems that `1 is not True`