# How "and" And "or" Operators work with 0 and 1 and numbers like 2,3,4etc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3.6.1 .

### Question 1:

#### A)

```
False and 0 # gives False, but   

0 and False # gives 0 (both answers must be False)
```

like that

```
False or 0 # gives 0, but

0 or False # gives False (both answers must be False)
```

Why is it not giving all results as False but give the one result as 0 (in number)?

Likewise

#### B)

```
True and 1 # gives 1, but

1 and True # gives True
```

Why aren't all results in case 'B' `True` and 1st one gives 1?
Why is it giving integers 1 and 0 as result (case A and B)? 
Is there any thing like direction in this?

### Question 2:

Do numbers other than or 0 & 1 like 2,3,4,-2,-3  represent `False` or `True` in any way?

#### C)

```
True == 1 # gives True 

True == 2 # gives False, but

True and 2 # gives False.
```

#### D)

```
False or 2 # gives 2

2 or False # gives 2
```

Are the other integers like 2,3 etc taken as `False`?
Why is it output in case D `2` and not `True` or `False`?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and make it readable? You can also mark text fragments as code, so that these stand out visually.

Comment: This question will be closed, because it is unclear/too broad in it's current form. If you ask one single clear question, then it can be marked with the appropriate duplicate

Answer (score 2):

`and` and `or` are boolean operators and their behaviour is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates x; if x is false, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates x; if x is true, its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

If these were functions they would look like (roughly) like this:

```
def and_function(x, y):
    if bool(x) == False:  # if x is false, its value is returned
        return x
    else:                 # otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned
        return y     

def or_function(x, y):
    if bool(x) == True:  # if x is true, its value is returned
        return x     
    else:                # otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
        return y
```

So these will always evaluate to either `x` or `y`, depending on the truth-value of the left side.

In this context "evaluate" refers to the *expression* not the *boolean value*. So `x or somefunction()` wouldn't evaluate the `somefunction()` if `bool(x) == True`. That's where the function equivalent fails because these functions don't postpone the evaluation of the expression. So don't take these two functions too seriously. They were only meant as explanation helpers.

---

The [truth-value testing documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) explains how the truth-value of numbers is defined:

> [...] The following values are considered false:
>
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.
> - [...]
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

---

Then you asked about equality between the booleans `True` and `False` and numbers. To understand this you have to know that bools are a subclass of integers in Python. In some sense `True` is just another name for `1` and `False` for `0`. So it's not surprising that `True == 1` and `False == 0` are both `True`.

NB: If you come from other languages it might be important to state that there is **no implicit casting for comparisons in Python**, I explained this in another answer in more details: ["Why does … == True return False?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43927120/5393381).